# Problems while Installing Redmine on Windows Server 2008

Tags: ruby-on-rails, project-management, rake, redmine

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 with MySQL and Subversion installed separately. Just to mention that it is also having IIS.

We are currently installing Redmine on the same server, and following instructions from this page:

http://www.richardnichols.net/2009/09/1-minute-guide-installing-redmine-on-windows/

While installing this  we’ve struck at step no. 8 with error on Rake aborted!

Here is the complete error text:

```
C:\Ruby187\Apps\Redmine>rake redmine:load_default_data RAILS_ENV=production
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on o
r after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/config/../vendor/rails/rail
ties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be
removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from C:/Ruby187/Apps/Redmine/config/../vendor
/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It wi
ll be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems
/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It wi
ll be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems
/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It wi
ll be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems
/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It wi
ll be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems
/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It wi
ll be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems
/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It wi
ll be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems
/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It wi
ll be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems
/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It wi
ll be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems
/source_index.rb:91.
rake aborted!
Could not find rack (~> 1.1.0) amongst [actionmailer-3.2.1, actionpack-3.2.1, ac
tivemodel-3.2.1, activerecord-3.2.1, activeresource-3.2.1, activesupport-3.2.1,
arel-3.0.0, builder-3.0.0, bundler-1.0.22, cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0, erubis-2
.7.0, gem_plugin-0.2.3, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.0, journey-1.0.1, json-1.6.5, mail-
2.4.1, mime-types-1.17.2, mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32, multi_json-1.0.4, mysql-2.8
.1-x86-mingw32, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.4.1, rack-cache-1.1, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack
-test-0.6.1, rails-3.2.1, railties-3.2.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.12, sprockets-2.3
.1, sprockets-2.1.2, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.31]

Tasks: TOP => redmine:load_default_data => environment
(See full trace by running task with –trace)
```

What could be causing this, and how to fix this. I'm not an expert at ROR.

---

Thanks daemonsly, As per your update, I have downgraded Ruby Gems version. Error has been changed, but still not able to proceed further. Here is the exact error I'm getting:

```
C:\Ruby187\Apps\Redmine>gem -v
1.6.2

C:\Ruby187\Apps\Redmine>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
RubyGem version error: rack(1.4.1 not ~> 1.1.0)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to downgrade your Ruby Gems version.

Try `gem update --system 1.6.2`

**Update**

Sorry, I have little experience with RoR on Windows. But basically, you should be having problems due to Redmine using older version of gems.

You should first try running `bundle install` to see if you already have all the specified gems. If rake still won't run, try `exec rake db:migrate`.

Finally, brute force if necessary.
`gem uninstall rack` then `gem install rack -v 1.1.0`

The premise of these actions is try to get the right gem versions.

Comment: Finally, if it still doesn't work, you can brute forcing it. `gem uninstall rack` and `gem install rack -v 1.1.0`

Comment: Uninstalling and installing rack again with version works fine. Thank you. :)